# Background worker on login page

Tags: c#, .net, backgroundworker

I'm doing a simple login form that will show the login process after they click button. It will verify the user access rights and give `true` or `false`.

I got an error on `this.Hide();`

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'formLogin' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.'

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!!

```
private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{            
    BackgroundWorker bgw = new BackgroundWorker();
    bgw.DoWork += bgw_DoWork;
    bgw.RunWorkerCompleted += bgw_RunWorkerCompleted;
    PBLogin.Style = ProgressBarStyle.Marquee;
    PBLogin.MarqueeAnimationSpeed = 50;
    bgw.RunWorkerAsync();
}
void bgw_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    PBLogin.Style = ProgressBarStyle.Blocks;
    PBLogin.MarqueeAnimationSpeed = 0;
}

void bgw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{          
     if (CheckAuthorization())
     {
         MessageBox.Show("Login Successfully");
         TestScript next = new TestScript();
         next.Show();
         this.Hide();
     }
     else 
     {
         MessageBox.Show("Login Failed");
     }
```

Comment: Make it thread safe with: this.Invoke(new Action(delegate() { your_code_here }));

Comment: You should pass the result of  `CheckAuthorization` via the `DoWorkEventArgs e` to the `bgw_RunWorkerCompleted` handler and do the handling from there, because that method runs on the UI thread again. You must not access UI (like with `Show` or `Hide`) from a background thread.

Comment: None of this needs to be in a thread

Answer (score 0):

From a background thread you can't reach the UI, that's what the exception is trying to tell you. In your background thread you should try to focus only on the Authorization logic itself. Try to avoid UI component manipulation.

In the `RunWorkerCompleted` event you can indeed modify the UI components. So, do the calculation on a dedicated background thread and do the UI manipulation inside the completion event.

```
void bgw_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    //TODO: Check against e.Error and e.Cancelled before you try to access e.Result
    if((bool)e.Result)
    {
       //UI modification
    }
    else
    {
      //UI modification
    }

}

void bgw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{          
     var isAuthorized = CheckAuthorization();
     e.Result = isAuthorized;
}
```